# Updating src path of an iframe using a HTML select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu, src

I am trying to use a HTML form element (specifically a select dropdown) to update the URL path of an iframe that is embedded on the page. This should reload the iframe each time a different selection is made.

I have tried the following using Javascript function to pass the value of the select when an onkeyup or onmouseup event happens, but I am not seeing any changes occur when this happens:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<style>

* {font-family: arial;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  document.monthyear.onkeyup = my;
  document.monthyear.onmouseup = my;

};

function my() {

var my = String(document.monthyear.value);

document.getElementById("iframe").src = my;

};

</script>

</head>

<body>

<select name="monthyear">
    <option value="/258001">
        January 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258002">
        February 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258003">
        March 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258004">
        April 2019
    </option>
</select>

<h1>Month</h1><iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="450" id="iframe" src="https://www.example.com/258001" style="border:0" width="800"></iframe>
```

Comment: You use `document.getElementById("my").value` but where is there an element with the id of `"my"`?

Comment: Sorry, now edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the default value of the select tag using the `selected` attribute, and then (see comments in code)...

```
<script>
const select = document.querySelector('#select')
window.onload = function() {
  // set the iframe value to default select value
  document.getElementById("iframe").src = '/258001'
};
// add an event listener that listens for a change to the input and sets the iframe path.
select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 document.getElementById("iframe").src = e.target.value
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.location.reload()
})

</script>

</head>

<body>

<select id="select" name="monthyear">
    <option value="/258001" selected="selected">
        January 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258002">
        February 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258003">
        March 2019
    </option>
    <option value="/258004">
        April 2019
    </option>
</select>

<h1>Month</h1><iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="450" id="iframe" src="https://www.example.com/258001" style="border:0" width="800"></iframe>
```

Comment: this doesn't reload the iframe after selecting another option in the drop-down?

Comment: No, sorry, still doesn't work: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at stack.html:10

Comment: It works for me. My guess is you're not adding the 'select' id to the HTML select element. Here's a working example, copied and pasted the code from my answer: https://codepen.io/sodapop/pen/YzzXvbo?editors=1111

Comment: Very strange. I can't get it to work even if I copy the code exactly and just wrap <html> around it and save in one file. Works on Codepen though.

Comment: Can you post what you have now? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I stupidly put the script in the head, thinking that was needed in order to set the default value. Realised my error and it works fine, but is 'document.getElementById("iframe").src = '/258001'' needed to set the default value anyway, if the iframe has a src in the html tag?

Comment: If you're setting the initial value directly in the HTML right away, you won't need to set it on load.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this:

```
 <select onchange='this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);'>
  <a href='#'><option>choose an action</option></a>
  <option value='Url or div'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='Url or div'>Option 2</option>

  </select>
```